# Given path not supported exception occured in file.copy method

Tags: c#

I've tried to copy the mainlist xml file to bin\Debug folder. But It throws exception. I've passed argument in console application like `"C:\Users\gio.frog\Desktop\mainlist.xml"` and used file.copy method like follows:

```
File.Copy(args[0], AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "sublist.xml",true);
```

I've seen some same exception example in stackoverflow but can't get the correct reason. How to copy to bin/debug folder.?

Comment: Try `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "sublist.xml");`

Comment: You're assuming `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` ends with a  \ which it may not, use `Path.Combine()`.

Comment: thank you all guys. It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` returns path without `\` at the end. When you combine it with a trying it will concatenate with directory name.

E.g. 
`"c:\projects\Debug\bin" + "sublist.xml"` will result in `"c:\projects\Debug\binsublist.xml"`

Use

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "sublist.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working now.